# Possible issue with [dcl.fct.def.general]/1 in the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[dcl.fct.def.general]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def#general-1):

> Function definitions have the form
>
> *function-definition*:
>      *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub>
> *decl-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *declarator* *virt-specifier-seq*<sub>*opt*</sub> *function-body*
>
> *function-body*:
>      *ctor-initializer*<sub>*opt*</sub>
> *compound-statement*
>      *function-try-block*
>      `= default ;`
>      `= delete ;`
>
> Any informal reference to the body of a function should be interpreted
> as a reference to the non-terminal
> *function-body*. The optional *attribute-specifier-seq* in a *function-definition* appertains to the function. A *virt-specifier-seq* can be part of a *function-definition* only if it is a *member-declaration* ([*class.mem*]).

Given that a function-declaration is a [*simple-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) and that the non-terminal symbol *decl-specifier-seq* in the definition of a *simple-declaration* is not optional, then it seems to me that a note like the one below would better clarify things in the last paragraph quoted above:

"The *decl-specififer_seq* is required in a non-member declaration."

Comment: "Given that a function-declaration is a simple-declaration" How is this related to function-**definition**?

Comment: @cpplearner Well, I don't know of any _function-definition_,  for a non-member function, that doesn't have a _defining_type-specifier_ in its _decl-specifier-seq_.